# Concept Application Server IDE CIDE will not launch on XP in IE8?

Tags: concept

I am trying with

concept://localhost/Samples/CIDE/cide.con

with the server running as an NT service

A few code examples run (many crash Client.exe but not the server) e.g.

concept://localhost/Samples/test.con

runs.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Concept Distibution (a conflict between gtk and gtkmm used by the Concept Client). Now the Concept Client has no more gtkmm bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Also, Samples is the default root, so the correct link is concept://localhost/CIDE/cide.con (without samples). You can also use the shortcuts in All Programs -> CIDE